# how do i get discord user's guilds in django allauth

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, discord, django-allauth

Im trying to get guilds that the discord user in.
i have added the scope to the `settings.py`

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS =  {
    'discord':  {
        'SCOPE': [
            'email',
            'identify',
            'guilds'
        ]
    }
}
```

i have added the app to the django admin dashboard and it works fine when i try to login using discord but when i add guilds scope it wont store the records anywhere as far as i looked for.

Comment: This has so few details it's impossible to give any answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.guilds) help you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking here but I'll try my best to help anyway.

According to the discord.py docs, there is no attribute for a users guilds, only a list of mutual guilds. You can get this list by simply referencing `user.mutual_guilds`. `mutual_guilds` is an attribute of the `discord.User` class and you can find out more about the user object and it's attributes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id7).

You can get a user from a member object using the bot client's get user method(s) by passing the member's ID. Again, further information can be found on the discord.py docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Again, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you will have to send an api request [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds)

you will need an oauth 2 token from the user though.

The request "Returns a list of partial guild objects the current user is a member of. Requires the guilds OAuth2 scope."